# What is the equivalent of status.get in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook

Can anyone tell me what is the equivalent of status.get of the Old REST API in the new Graph API. 
The page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ says "If you are new to the Facebook Platform, we recommend you use our new Graph API instead." so I'm trying to figure out the newer version.
Basically, what I want is to retrieve the status messages that a user has updated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>/statuses`

You can also use [FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/user-status) or [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status).

Comment: Thank you. It's just what I'm looking for!! \m/